# ASP.NET Web API HTTPRequestMessage with CLR Object to upload file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-web-api

I want to upload file to server using ASP.NET Web API with Security token in header and embed CLR object in the `HTTPRequestMessage`.

I can find solution to POST file using Web API Async with multipart content type but there is no solution to upload with custom HTTP request message with header token...

I am using the below code

```
    public HttpResponseMessage UploadImportFile()
    {
        List<string> FileIdentifiers = new List<string>();

        // Check if the request contains multipart/form-data.
        if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
        }

        string root = ImportFileDirectory;
        MultipartFormDataStreamProvider provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root);

        try
        {
            // Read the form data.
            Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

            foreach (MultipartFileData file in provider.FileData)
            {
                FileIdentifiers.Add(file.LocalFileName.Replace(root, "").Replace("BodyPart_", ""));
            }
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new FileUploadResponseType(Ackowledgememt.Success, UtcDateTime.Now, null, version, FileIdentifiers));
        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
            log.Error(e);
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, e);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to implement it in web API. If you want to pass a security token in the HTTP header, a good candidate would be to implement an authorization filter that is added to your upload file operation; the filter would validate the security token by looking in the request message header; if the validation succeeded, the request would flow through; otherwise the filter can throw an exception (such as HttpResponseException) so that the request is rejected.

Comment: I hve updated the question with code which I am using to upload file. If I include custom httprequestmessage as input. the below operation is not invoked. How to post file with httprequestmessage